# Real VNC on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS via xinetd

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, xinetd

I am trying to get Real VNC server on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64 bit.

I tried 2 options. First, I got Real VNC free edition and got it working after getting all requires 32 bit libraries, configuration hacking etc. It's almost good with one little problem, after I disconnect client, server prints `Aborted` and exits. I tried many combination of parameters and could not figure it.

This is roughly a command line I used (but I tried many parameter combinations).

```
Xvnc :2 -desktop user-desktop -query localhost -geometry 1920x1200 -depth 16 -AcceptCutText -SendCutText -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd -SecurityTypes None -DisconnectClients
```

Second option. I got trial version of Real VNC Enterprise 4.6.1 and installed it. Now I can happily start it as standalone server and my clients can disconnect without killing server but when I try to use it with `-inetd` option it just silently exits. When I try free edition it would go into stdio mode and print handshake message

```
RFB 003.008
```

Not the case with enterprise edition. It just exits. No message and no logs.

So does anyone have any idea on how to get either option work?

---

Per recommendation from @grawity I run `strace` and `ltrace`. Here is most interesting output from ltrace (I collected data in file called abc and only pasted lines that I find interesting):

```
$cat abc | egrep 'strchr|print'

fprintf(0x7f330223e860, "\n%s", "Sun Jul 10 13:07:30 2011\n") = 26
strchr("inetd client gone, exiting", ' ')        = " client gone, exiting"
strchr("client gone, exiting", ' ')              = " gone, exiting"
strchr("gone, exiting", ' ')                     = " exiting"


$ cat abc | egrep 'strchr|print' | grep socket
strchr("getpeername: Socket operation on"..., ' ') = " Socket operation on non-socket "...
strchr("Socket operation on non-socket ("..., ' ') = " operation on non-socket (88)"
strchr("operation on non-socket (88)", ' ')      = " on non-socket (88)"
strchr("on non-socket (88)", ' ')                = " non-socket (88)"
strchr("non-socket (88)", ' ')                   = " (88)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running it under `ltrace` or `strace`.

It could be that the *inetd* mode requires that *stdin* and *stdout* be sockets – for example, this is required for determining the client's IP address. It's likely that RealVNC isn't prepared for `getpeername()` to return failure.

Alternatively, use Xvnc.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning strace and ltrace. You may be right about sockets. I updated my question with output of ltrace. But what do I do next to solve it?

Comment: @Alex: The problem shouldn't happen when running RealVNC under *real* xinetd. Have you tried that already?

Comment: I tried from real xinetd. I can connect, see X screen for a second and then it dies. I also can't figure how to get log from vnc.

Comment: Try a packet sniffer; error messages usually go to stderr, which is sent over the same socket by xinetd. Also check `dmesg` for program crashes, and `/var/log/messages`|`/var/log/syslog`|`/var/log/everything.log` for VNC logs.

Comment: Actually, I accidentally :( found vnc log. Not sure why my attempts to direct it to specific place fail. It always just says that `inetd client is gone`. But anyway, apparently there is a permission issue. I changed user in xinetd config file to myself and now I can connect. However, it still dies once I disconnect client. I think there was an option to xinetd that controls it.  I am browsing through docs and will probably find it, but do you remember on top of your head?

Comment: @Alex: What if you change the user to `root`? Also, in inetd mode, the server is *supposed to* exit after losing TCP connection.

Comment: If server dies after disconnect that would defeat much of the purpose of vnc for me. For example, I work on my laptop, connect and then just  step out for coffee. Laptop goes into power save and I lose my session. I am pretty sure that it didn't happen to me with Red Hat setups. I will try root, although vnc docs clearly say that it should not be done.

Comment: @Alex: Then don't use it in inetd mode; run it as a daemon.

Comment: root makes no difference. It still exits.

Comment: I was about to use it as daemon. But finally I set `wait=yes` and it seems to address my problem. Hooray! Which actually makes sense as I want to just always connect to the same instance of my server.